# Django query for the top 5

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have this  two model:

```html
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("State",max_length=255)
```

```html
class Breakdowns(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="State")
    date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="Date")
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

As you can see i can have 1 State with severeal breakdows. How can i show the top 5 state's with more breakdowns ?

Comment: How do you know it's a top 5 state?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @monkut the top 5 is the state's with more breakdwons

Comment: Please ask a proper question, what is a top state? Which criteria need to be fullfilled? do you have a score or something? Should we just guess what the `State` model looks like?

Comment: Pedro, you need to clarify this question before gets deleted, explain what criteria should satisfy the "top classification", you should take one field for grouping/sorting the property you want to show "the top 5", with the info you provide I only can guess about "date" like top 5 first breakdowns today: `Breakdowns.objects.filter(date=datetime.now().date()).order_by("-date")[0:5]`

Comment: it is literally an example in documentation

Comment: @iklinac already see it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count_breakdowns = State.objects.annotate(num_Breakdowns=Count('Breakdowns')).order_by('-num_Breakdowns')[:5]

Comment: Few tips regarding coding style, model names should be singular and variables should be snake_case
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/